# Maatwebsite\Excel in Laravel- Border is not showing in excel after filling background color

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and maatwebsite/excel 2.1, the issue is  border line is not showing after setting background color, I have used the below code.

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setBorder('A1:' . $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn() . 
                                    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow(), 'thin');
```

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UIhN.png)

Comment: Do you already check this resource:  https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#styling

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, I have checked it. This code is working fine in one production but not in another one.  What could be the reason for this issue?